# How to filter based on clipboard in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, clipboard

I work with a bunch of people in my department and always share my code with them so you'll be helping me and my coworkers as well!

Using the macro recorder I have created this code to filter the column I want filtered, but I need to change the code to filter it based on what ever is on the clipboard (what ever cell I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on previously).  I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while recording the macro but it didn't record those button presses, it only pasted what was in my clipboard at the time into the macro.

```
Sub Filter()

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$V$12955").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "Clipboard"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use the value of the cell and forget the clipboard?

Comment: the cell that will be used will be changing.  it also may not always be coming from excel.  would like to know how to access clipboard for such functions for this macro as well as future macros i may create.  i did extensive google searches as well as searching this website before asking.  thank you.

Comment: You can access the clipboard using the `MSForms.DataObject`. But in the issue where the cell value may be changing, then assign the value to a variable and work with that. That is the purpose of variables, you shouldn't be using your clipboard as a variable.

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the First Projects That I did in Excel. I will explain How my code is working, then you can manipulate this according to your need.

[Youtube Link on How to Use it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0GjqeT7IAU)

After Pasting the code in your `Personal Macro`, Create a Shortcut on the Quick Access ToolBar for this Macro.

Then All you need to do is, Apply `Autofilter` on the Range you want to Filter, Copy the Cell or the Range of Cells that contains the value you want to filter, and select the header of the column on which  you want to apply this Filter. Press the Created Shortcut.

**It will work on the Single Cell Also, So you don't need to amend it. Just follow the Instructions Above.**

Here Is the Code:

```
Sub filtrr()
'
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Test As String
    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

    clipboard.GetFromClipboard
    Test = clipboard.GetText

    Test = Replace(Test, Chr(13), "-")
    Test = Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(Test))

    Dim ab() As String

    ab = Split(Test, "-")

    ReDim Preserve ab(UBound(ab) - 1)

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=Selection.Column, Criteria1:=ab, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues


End Sub
```

In your case it's only One cell that contains value, but this code is a life saver if you want to filter like 50 values in a table of thousands of values.