# AutoFilter Criteria Range Not taking an Array

Tags: excel, vba

**1**. I have data in one sheet and want to filter the list of criteria in another column

**2**. I want to have the criteria in separate WS as well

I have included 2 separate codes below

1. code for same sheet list Array

   ```
   Sub FilterTeams()

   Dim LastRow As Long

   LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*" & Range("Q1") & "*"

   End Sub
   ```
2. list array in other sheet
   [code details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa7YO.jpg)

   ```
   Sub Filter()

   Dim Criteria As Variant
   Criteria = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A140")
   Worksheets("AP").Range("$A$1:$h$100").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues

   End Sub
   ```

it is filtering only the first value and not all values in the column

(it should filter all values contains)

Comment: are any rows hidden in column A? Using `End(xlUp)` bypasses hidden (filtered rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
You are defining your `array` from a `Range`, that gives you a `2D array`, which you cannot pass into `Autofilter` Easily. So we have to change it into `1D Array`.

**Solution:** Change your second code to this:

```
Sub Filter()

Dim Criteria As Variant
Dim cri() As String

Criteria = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A140")

ReDim Preserve cri(UBound(Criteria))

For I = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)

    cri(I) = Criteria(I, 1)

Next

Worksheets("AP").Range("$A$1:$h$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cri, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

**Alternative:** The code that you are using is Fixed Code. There is one Dynamic code that could be also of use for you. Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56607423/5720144).

Comment: @Moras ... Accept the Answer if it worked for you. :)